# About inputs in PICAXE 28X1

Tags: microcontroller, picaxe

I have to check this inputs in BASIC with PICAXE 28X1:

[image]

But I have no clue how I'm supposed to do that.

A.0 or pinA.0 don't work, and input0 refers to pin 11.

So how can I check pins 2 - 5..?

Any help is appreciated~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax was:

```
porta pin0
porta pin1
porta pin2
   ···
```

Hope this can help someone :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple if you have not yet figured it out. Here is a sample code that will detect if the input pin you specified is high or not, and then do something. If this does not work still, let me know. Hope it helps!

```
main:
    low A.0
    low A.1
    low A.2
    low A.3
    if A.0 = high then do
    if A.1 = high then do
    if A.2 = high then do
    if A.3 = high then do
    goto main
do:
    high B.6
    wait 5
    low B.5
    goto main
```